# How to get all data from specific keys in PHP array, if array can have any size and nesting?

Tags: php, arrays

It's a very specific question, sorry if my description is not clear enough.
I have an array which looks like that:

```
    [conditions] => Array
    (
        [set] => all
        [set_value] => 1
        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [operator] => eq
                        [condition] => price
                        [value] => 500
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [set] => all
                        [set_value] => 1
                        [conditions] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [operator] => in
                                        [condition] => users
                                        [value] => 3
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [set] => all
                        [set_value] => 1
                        [conditions] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [set] => all
                                        [set_value] => 1
                                        [conditions] => Array
                                            (
                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [operator] => in
                                                        [condition] => categories
                                                        [value] => 168
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [operator] => eq
                                        [condition] => payment
                                        [value] => 13
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

So basically, it's an array with the main key being group of "conditions", but each condition can also contain another group of conditions, and every condition there can contain another group etc.

This process can continue indefinetely, I don't know how many nestings array will have.

My goal is to get all the "final" conditions, the ones which do not have another group inside of them. So, for my test input, the result should be:

```html
[1] => Array
(
    [operator] => eq
    [condition] => price
    [value] => 500
),
[2] => Array
(
    [operator] => in
    [condition] => users
    [value] => 3
),
[3] => Array
(
    [operator] => in
    [condition] => categories
    [value] => 168
),
[4] => Array
(
    [operator] => eq
    [condition] => payment
    [value] => 13
)
```

(sorry for using snipper, somehow code sample is not working with that one.)

How do I even approach such problem? Foreach doesn't seem usable here, and I can't figure out how should I run recursion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function:

```
function getConditions($array, &$result) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (array_key_exists('conditions', $array)) {
            getConditions($array['conditions'], $result);
        } else {
            foreach($array as $item) {
                if (array_key_exists('condition', $item)) {
                    $result[] = $item;
                } elseif (array_key_exists('conditions', $item)) {
                    getConditions($item['conditions'], $result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = [];
getConditions($myConditions, $result);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: It worked! I had a similar idea, but I did foreach first without any if-s before it. Thank you very much! :)